# Android asynchronus HTTP client problem

Tags: android, asynchronous, httpresponse

I am trying to implement asynchronus http client for Android and I am haveing a trouble with type mismatch:

```
The method execute(HttpUriRequest) in the type HttpClient is not applicable for the arguments (HttpRequest)
```

I am doing all based on this tutorial: http://blog.androgames.net/12/retrieving-data-asynchronously/

Have found a type in AsynchronousSender - private HttpRequest request; but I have still problem with above which occurs in:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        final HttpResponse response;
        synchronized (httpClient) {
            response = getClient().execute(request); //<-- here is that problem
        }
        // process response
        wrapper.setResponse(response);
        handler.post(wrapper);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Can you suggest anything ?

cheers,
/Marcin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippets on http://blog.androgames.net/12/retrieving-data-asynchronously/ are wrong. To fix it just replace [HttpRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpRequest.html) with [HttpUriRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest.html) since the method signature is: [HttpClient#execute(HttpUriRequest)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html#execute%28org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest%29). It shouldn't be any problem since most requests you work with are HttpUriRequest instances.

Comment: Not working that way as protected AsynchronousSender(HttpRequest request... method is expecting request to be HttpRequest type

Comment: @Marcin: Yes, but AsynchronousSender snippet is _incorrect_ - you should update it and replace HttpRequest with HttpUriRequest.